# GUID in dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to use a column of type uniqueidentifier in Dynamic SQL.

I have a table X, with column ID of type guid.

If I do:

```
declare @primarykeyvalue varchar(50)  
set @primarykeyvalue = '648D2DD7-0EB1-4E29-A996-69456753C460'  

select * from X where ID = @primarykeyvalue
```

This works, but if I try to do the same in dynamic SQL like:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)   
SET @sql = 'select * from X where ID = ' + @primarykeyvalue  
EXECUTE(@sql)
```

This gives an syntax error as Incorrect syntax near 'D2DD7'.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need extra quotes around your GUID value:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)   
SET @sql = 'select * from X where ID = ''' + @primarykeyvalue + ''''

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Answer (score 6):

Change your code to:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)   
SET @sql = 'select * from X where ID = ''' + @primarykeyvalue + ''''  
EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Maybe you should think about using `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)   
SET @sql = 'select * from X where ID = @key'  

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@key nvarchar(50)', @key = @primarykeyvalue
```

This enables you to use parameters in your queries and gets rid of the nasty doubled
single quotes.